# Count consecutive strings per column with groupby and cumcount (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` which looks like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"child": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "D", "A"],
                            "birth": ["2000-07-29", "2000-08-03", "2000-09-10", "2000-09-10", "2000-11-02", "2000-09-10", "2000-07-29"],
                            "parent": ["Z", "Z", "V", "V", "O", "V", "Z"],
                            "logic": ["abc", "abc", "efg", "efg", "opk", "zlm", "zlm"]})
```

I would like to add a column `count` that shows how many *unique* children each parent has until the given `birth`date.

Desired outcome `df_new`:

```
child     birth        parent    logic      count
A         2000-07-29   Z         abc        1
B         2000-08-03   Z         abc        2
C         2000-09-10   V         efg        2
D         2000-09-10   V         efg        2
E         2000-11-02   O         opk        1
```

I tried the following code:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df)
df_new = df_new.drop_duplicates(subset=["parent", "child"]).sort_values(by=["parent", "birth"])
df_new["count"] = df_new.groupby("parent").cumcount()+1
```

Firstly, i dropped duplicates based on `parent` and `child` so that the same child won't be added up. Then, I sorted `df_new` by `parent` and `birth` so that it is possible to count consecutively the occurences of `parent` with `cumcount` in order to visualize the number of children per parent.

**Unfortunately, it does not consider multiple occurences on the same date**.

Achieved outcome `df_new`:

```
child     birth        parent    logic      count
A         2000-07-29   Z         abc        1
B         2000-08-03   Z         abc        2
C         2000-09-10   V         efg        1      # this should be 2 as well! 
D         2000-09-10   V         efg        2
E         2000-11-02   O         opk        1
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue? Feel free to suggest other methods! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to OPs except with a [`groupby count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) + [`groupby cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) instead of `groupby cumsum` + 1:

```
# Ensure datetime for correct ordering
df['birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birth'])

# Remove duplicates
# and sort by birth so later cumsum values are in correct order
grp_keys = ["parent", "birth"]
new_df = (
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=["parent", "child"])
        .sort_values(by=grp_keys)
)

new_df = new_df.join(
    new_df.groupby(grp_keys)['child']
        .count()  # Count children in parent birth groups
        .groupby(level=0)
        .cumsum()  # cumsum based on parent (level=0)
        .rename('count'),
    on=grp_keys  # Join back to original dataframe
).sort_index()  # restore initial order
```

`new_df`:

```
  child      birth parent logic  count
0     A 2000-07-29      Z   abc      1
1     B 2000-08-03      Z   abc      2
2     C 2000-09-10      V   efg      2
3     D 2000-09-10      V   efg      2
4     E 2000-11-02      O   opk      1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to solve:

```
df = (
    df_new.set_index(['parent', 'birth'])
    .join(
        df_new.groupby('parent')
        .apply(lambda x: x.groupby('birth')['child'].agg('count').cumsum()),
        rsuffix='count')
    .reset_index()
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
  parent      birth child logic  childcount
0      O 2000-11-02     E   opk           1
1      V 2000-09-10     C   efg           2
2      V 2000-09-10     D   efg           2
3      Z 2000-07-29     A   abc           1
4      Z 2000-08-03     B   abc           2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```py
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["parent", "child"])
x = (
    df.pivot_table(index="parent", columns="birth", aggfunc="size")
    .cumsum(axis=1)
    .stack()
    .rename("count")
    .astype(int)
)
print(df.set_index(["parent", "birth"]).join(x).reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
  parent       birth child logic  count
0      O  2000-11-02     E   opk      1
1      V  2000-09-10     C   efg      2
2      V  2000-09-10     D   efg      2
3      Z  2000-07-29     A   abc      1
4      Z  2000-08-03     B   abc      2
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! As I'm rather a beginner in python, could you help me understand why it prints the right output with your solution but does not adjust `df` when removing the `print()` function?

Comment: @mcm You need to assign back to `df`, for example: `df = df.set_index(["parent", "birth"]).join(x).reset_index()`. Then `print(df)` will print modified dataframe.